# docker-compose get ID of a docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose, with a docker-compose.yml file.

Is there a way to get in .yml, the ID of another docker (which is in the same docker-compose.yml)?

docker-compose.yml:

```
containerA:
  command: python -u catch_sig.py 
  volumes: 
    - /workspace:/app
containerB:
  command: echo -e "POST /containers/containerA/kill?signal=SIGUSR1 HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /tmp/docker.sock
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the ID?

Comment: it will be use to send an automate signal.

Comment: Another reason to want the ID is to do things like `docker logs`

Answer (score 14):

With newer docker-compose versions (I have 1.8.0) you can do

```
$ docker-compose ps -q
```

Which will only display the id.
See the usage.

```
 $ docker-compose ps --help
 List containers.

 Usage: ps [options] [SERVICE...]

 Options:
   -q    Only display IDs
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to display the names along with their IDs?

Comment: @Sankalp you can use this command for it: `docker-compose ps --services | awk '{ print "echo -n \""$1": \" ; docker-compose ps -q "$1 }' | bash`. I've described the details here: https://zinovyev.net/list-docker-compose-service-ids

Answer (score 13):

You can get the ID of a container in this way:

```
docker-compose ps -q [container-name]
```

Comment: FYI you have to strip the extra stuff off the name returned from `docker-compose ps` to get the underlying container name - it should be the name as written in your docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 4):

To get all Ids containers:

```
docker-compose ps -q
```

If you need get one Id:

```
docker-compose ps -q some_name_container_in_yml_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Docker client to containerB and then set the DOCKER_HOST environment to the underlying host (be sure to configure its settings so it accepts TCP connections on the network). Then, you can do a `docker inspect containerA` using the container name to identify the host you are querying.

This should give you the container id for containerA.